# How to insert values into a database (Microsoft access)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, insert

I'm trying to insert details of a user into a table called user in my database, however i think there's something wrong with how i wrote the query responsible in doing so.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public static void addUser(string n, string s)
{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
    string myQuery = "INSERT INTO user( Name, Surname) VALUES ( '" + n + " , " + s + "' )";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception or an error?

Comment: i think so because when i debug it, it try's to catch an exception and nothing is added to the database.

Comment: Use the answer given by @Soner Gönül

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**  you are misusing single quotes.

**Solution :**  you need to enclose the `VARCHAR` types in single quotes properly

Try This:

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO [user] ([Name],Surname) VALUES ( '" + n + "' , '" + s + "' )";
```

I suggest you to use `Parameterised sql queries` to avoid `Sql Injection attacks`

Try This: with **Parameterised Queries**

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO [user]([Name], Surname) VALUES (@name,@surname)";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",n);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname",s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you didn't tell us you get any error or not but using [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) is always a better option. This kinf of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

For example;

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO [user] ([Name], Surname) VALUES (@n, @s)";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", n);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s);
```

Also `user` and `Name` are [`reserved keywords`](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) on MS Access. You should use them with square brackets like `[user]` and `[Name]`.

As a general recomendation, don't use reserved keywords for your identifiers and object names in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple apostrophes.

The way you've got it, instead of passing two parameters (i.e. `'one'` and `'two'`), you're passing a single parameter (i.e. `'one , two'`).

Try this:

```
string myQuery
    = "INSERT INTO user( Name, Surname) VALUES ( '" + n + "' , '" + s + "' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that 'user' is a keyword for MS Access. You must put it in angle brackets: `[user]`.

HTH Thomas